# Android Studio 2.1.3, intel haxm issue, Android studio doesn't recognize uninstalled intelhaxm

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, haxm

Android studio won't react to "uninstalled" Haxm . It keeps showing the message "Virtual machine acceleration driver is out-of-date. Reinstall inter Haxm."

On my windows 7 machine, I recently installed Android Studio 2.1.3. In SDK manager I also first installed intel haxm installer 6.0.3. However when I open AVD manager to create virtual device the error occurs - `"Virtual machine acceleration driver is out-of-date. Reinstall inter Haxm."`.

I tried - 
**1)** I tracked the intelhaxm.exe file under the sdk folder and ran installation with administrative rights. Result = Same error message appears.

**2)** I uninstalled intelhaxm installed by SDK manager. Obtained the IntelHaxm installer from the Intel site and manually installed it. Result = Same error message appears.

Note: Curiously under the Registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->HAXM->HAXM, I see Haxm binery data value "0" but I expect it to be "1"!

**3)** After frustrated 3 days with no help by googling, I uninstalled the intelhaxm. EVEN THEN, the same error message appears in the AVD manager. when I have none intelhaxm installed, how can it report "Intelhaxm is out-of-date, reinstall" ?

Is the AVD manager not looking at the intelhaxm on my system at all? Is it a Haxm problem? or it is a Android Studio problem?

"Help is need desperately".